# Regex how can I check that message isn't empty

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I check if a string isn't empty using regex? For example, if the user give a lot of space characters whitout letters, it will be considered as empty

I've tried `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to check if there's a letter in the string, but this don't work.

Comment: Empty string can be detected as `^\s*$`

Comment: @rock321987 Sounds like an answer.

Comment: @rock321987 working, please make an answer to be able to validate it

Comment: The *this don't work* is very unclear. You should always clarify what does not work and how it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect an empty string (containing zero or more spaces) using this regex

```
^\s*$
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to use Regex if you are allowing everything other than empty string, you can just use `trim()` which will trim white spaces.

```
Boolean("       ".trim()); //false
Boolean("     b ".trim()); //true
Boolean("\n\t\r ".trim()); //false
Boolean("\n\th\r".trim()); //true
```

Comment: It's a valid solution too, however OP asked: *"How can I check if a string isn't empty using regex?"*.

Comment: @dfsq If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail. OP may not be aware that a regex isn't necessary here.

Comment: @dfsq Just a suggestion incase it helps someone at sometime :)

Comment: I like your solution, it's better than regex, but I can't validate it beacause in the question I've said regex, but I've upvoted you

Comment: Thank you for the nice words, glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if it contains any non-whitespace (i.e. printing) characters:

```
\S
```

That's backslash capital `S`.